# Замена нескольких подстрок в строке с помощью одной команды

Tags: регулярные-выражения, строки, excel, vba, replace

Хочу заменить в строке разные подстроки (заменить html спецсимволы).

Сейчас у меня работает такой код:

```
' заменить &xxx символы '
Dim termsDictionary As Object
Set termsDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
termsDictionary.Add "&amp;", "&"
termsDictionary.Add "&lt;", "<"
termsDictionary.Add "&gt;", ">"
termsDictionary.Add "&nbsp;", " "
termsDictionary.Add "&sect;", "§"
termsDictionary.Add "&copy;", "©"
termsDictionary.Add "&reg;", "®"
termsDictionary.Add "&deg;", "°"
termsDictionary.Add "&laquo;", "«"
termsDictionary.Add "&raquo;", "»"
termsDictionary.Add "&middot;", "·"
termsDictionary.Add "&trade;", "™"
termsDictionary.Add "&plusmn;", "±"

For Each Key In termsDictionary.Keys()
    RemoveHTML = Replace(RemoveHTML, Key, termsDictionary(Key))
Next
```

Но он, как мне кажется очень топорный и в лоб :(
Можно ли это сделать как-нибудь одной командой? Возможно через регулярные выражения.

Т.е. найти &xxx; или &xxx (в конце отсутствует ;) и заменить на соответствующий символ из списка.

Comment: Нет смысла использовать регулярное выражение в случае, когда разные символы надо заменить на другие неодинаковые символы. Кстати, [вам уже дали совет на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378386/replace-several-substrings-to-several-substrings-in-single-string-using-vba-exc).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, есть в некоторых случаях смысл. Например, стандартный Replace может захватить часть слова, а нужно реплейсить слово целиком

Comment: @iluxa1810 , можно ведь делать замены с добавлением пробелов, например: *Trim(Replace(" " & "abc a" & " ", " a ", ""))*

Answer (score 0):

Регулярные выражения при замене разных символов на другие неодинаковые символы неэффективны, так как можно указать только один вариант замены. Например, если необходимо заменить все `&laquo;`, `&apos;` и `&raquo;` на `"`, тогда можно использовать `&(?:apos|[lr]aquo);` и заменить на `"`.

В данном случае вы можете использовать текущий код, т.е. `Scripting.Dictionary`, в качестве общего решения проблемы.

Для замены HTML-сущностей можно использовать `HTMLDocument`:

```
Public Function HTMLToCharCodes(ByVal iString As String) As String
    Dim odoc As Object
    Set odoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    odoc.Open
    odoc.write iString
    odoc.Close
    HTMLToCharCodes = odoc.body.innerText
    Debug.Print HTMLToCharCodes
End Function
```

Пример:

```
HTML = "k&amp;&lt;&gt;&nbsp;&sect;&copy;&reg;&deg;&laquo;&raquo;&middot;&trade;&plusmn;"
Debug.Print HTMLToCharCodes(HTML)
// => k&<> §©®°«»·™±
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function fRepl_(sStr As String) As String
    Dim arr1(), arr2()
    Dim sTemp As String, j As Long
    
    arr1 = Array("&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&nbsp;", "&sect;", "&copy;", "&reg;", _
                    "&deg;", "&laquo;", "&raquo;", "&middot;", "&trade;", "&plusmn;")
    arr2 = Array("&", "<", ">", " ", "$", "©", "®", "°", "«", "»", "·", "™", "±")
    sTemp = sStr
    
    For j = 0 To UBound(arr1)
        sTemp = Replace(sTemp, arr1(j), arr2(j))
    Next j

    fRepl_ = sTemp
End Function
```